# Changing image url when profile image is updated

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a an android app using firebase. The app has users and these users have profile images. The user can like, create and comment on a post.I currently have a data structure where the user id, name and download image URL are all saved in the post the user created, the like object and also in the comment object. I did this because i did not want to query for the user object each time there is a comment or post just to display the name and profile image. It would mean if there are, say 30 post and each by a different person, i would have to query for all 30 users just to get the name and image url. The issue i have now is each time the user updates that image i have to look through and find all comments, post and likes they have made and update those with the new downlaod url. Is there a better way to save these variable that would be easy to retrieve and update.

here is my post object

```
public class Post implements Parcelable {

    private String postId;
    private String title;
    private String body;
    private CreatedBy createdBy;
    private String parentId;
    @ServerTimestamp
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date updatedAt;

    public Post(){

    }
}
```

and the created by object

```
Public class CreatedBy implements Parcelable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String imageUrl;
    private CreatorType creatorType;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually very simple you just listen for `Task` and update the Realtime Database with the user's path.

> You're probably gonna insert the image in `onActivityResult()` after getting some data.

```
// uploadTask is StorageReference's task
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content
        taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
        // Update the users node in Realtime Database with the URL
        // If you're using image loading library like Glide it should update
        // automatically
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks jake for the response! If i understand your response correctly, you are saying i should update the users image url with the download image url from the task? If that is the case, I already do this, the issue comes with having to update all post and comments and like the user has created with the new image url. Because of the data structure i currently have, where the user image url is saved within each post. This is done, to avoid multiple reads of the user object.

Comment: I get you, but i consider that bad practice because the data can change and that means it needs to be synchronized on each post which can also be very expensive. thus reading it from one path is better than synchronizing in every posts :)

Comment: ah okay, so the solution is to query for the user data each time? or do i update the image metadata with the users id and name?

Comment: Yes query for user's path in the Realtime Database if you already have the updated image profile URL and you don't have to do anything with the Firebase Storage's metadata, assuming that it is properly structured.

Comment: Okay that sounds good, I am using cloud firestore, I assume it would be the same. solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know is hard to make sense for who's come from relational database world. I know that because i come from a SQL database world. But when need change a data, all places where have this duplicate exists, the data need be updated. I know this sound terible, but, make sense when we think how many times a comment, post and likes are be reading in one day, in comparasion in how many times the user change the profile image.

For example, if you put in a comment with just a key to user profile, every time anyone request a comment, you need request the comment and request the author. This make a massive increase of reads on your database. And all of this just to need update a profile image in a one place.

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ&t=326s